# Bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't appear onlcick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying to add navbar to my website so
I copied the code from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) website but It dropdown menu doesn't work

Here is the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

And This is the CSS in head tag and SCRIPTS at the end of the page before body tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-style.css" />

<script type="text/jscript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.js" />
<script type="text/jscript" src="js/bootstrap.js" />
```

I haven't changed any thing it's all copy from Bootstrap I have just remove unwanted links from navbar.
I need help...Thanks all
NOTE: Bootstrap version 3.3.6

Comment: Hey, make sure you place the styles between your `<head>` tag and all the scripts before `</body>` tag.

Comment: which version of bootstrap ?

Comment: Version bootstrap-3.3.6

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code. The problem is with the compatibility of JQuery 3.0 with Bootstrap. You may read more using the link below.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834

As for now, I suggest you fallback to JQuery 2.2.4 until Bootstrap updates their 3.x version.

I tried reproducing your code in codepen and it seems to be working with JQuery 2.2.4.

Comment: Thanks .. the wrong was script self tag. it must be like that<script src=""> </script> NOT <script  src="" /> and bootstrap needs jquery version lower than 3.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to copy this html code below and compare what's wrong with yours.
Note that I used cdn to call bootstrap and jquery sources. See also where I placed the sources. Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
     </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks .. the wrong was script self tag. it must be like that<script src=""> </script> NOT <script  src="" /> and bootstrap needs jquery version lower than 3.

Answer (score 1):

The info you linked is great and you're almost there!

What you need to do from here is put everything besides the **link** tags inside of **body** tags, which also sit inside of **html** tags. If that's confusing, look at the html file I've made below. Also, don't forget your DOCTYPE tag at the top of the file.

After you've done that, put the **link** tags inside of a the **head** element above the **body** tag. Hopefully that makes sense.

At this point you may see that what you called CSS is a part of the html file. CSS files are linked to HTML files via the **link** tags in the head of an HTML file.

Check out the W3C website for more information about the differences between HTML and CSS http://www.w3schools.com/.

This might be information overload, but your script tags src is telling your html file to go to a folder/file tree, which you need to create or it will not do anything. That is where you put the Javascript files you're referencing there. That also applies to your CSS src property.

Cheers!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-style.css" />
      <title>My Bootstrap Title</title>
    </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        <script type="text/jscript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.js" />
        <script type="text/jscript" src="js/bootstrap.js" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks .. the wrong was script self tag. it must be like that<script src=""> </script> NOT <script  src="" /> and bootstrap needs jquery version lower than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, you can put the css your `<head></head>` tag

**Bootstrap CDN**

```
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

---

```
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

---

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>
```

**learn more about it** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

[Working sample](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rszjg0yw/)

Comment: Thanks .. the wrong was script self tag. it must be like that<script src=""> </script> NOT <script  src="" /> and bootstrap needs jquery version lower than 3.

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing your code and for the drop-down menu issue to work out, all you need to do is to add the below scripts at the end of the HTML page just above the close body tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks .. the wrong was script self tag. it must be like that<script src=""> </script> NOT <script  src="" /> and bootstrap needs jquery version lower than 3.